# How to make the simplest HelloWorld servlet with maven without web.xml

Tags: maven, servlet-4

As a green hand, I created a HelloWorld servlet:

```
package com.rx.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("<html><body>Hello World</body</html>");
  }
}
```

Then there is the following configuration in my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>rx.helloworld</groupId>
<artifactId>simpleservlet</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simpleservlet Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<war.name>simpleservlet</war.name>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<servlet.version>4.0.1</servlet.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>${servlet.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>${war.name}</finalName><!-- name of the bundled project when it is finally built -->
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>9.3.9.v20160517</version>
      <configuration>
        <httpConnector>
          <!--host>localhost</host-->
        </httpConnector>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I read from servlet specification document, where told that

> > A web application is NOT required to contain a web.xml if it does NOT contain any
> >     Servlet, Filter, or Listener components or is using annotations to declare the same. In
> >     other words an application containing only static files or JSP pages does not require
> >     a web.xml to be present.

I indeed used the `@WebServlet`, so did not include the `web.xml`.

The full code base is [here](https://github.com/rxue/HelloWorld/tree/master/backend/simpleservlet)

**Question:** But when I try to run it with *jetty* with command `mvn jetty:run`, I can't find my servlet at all. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Jetty will support servlet 4.0 at [version 10](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1799). However, the web.xml is optional in servlet 3.1.0, too. Your servlet is not responding at `http://localhost:8080/helloworld`?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually figured out by myself, say it missed a configuration in the maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `failOnMissingWebXml` should be configured `false`, which is not the default value